# date_range_start="today" shows events from yesterday

Tags: solspace-calendar

Is there something wrong with this `cal` tag, or is it Calendar's fault? It insists on showing events from yesterday!

```
{exp:calendar:cal date_range_start="today" show_months="12" calendar_name="events"  dynamic="on" category="{segment_4}"}
<a href="{path='events/booking'}/{event_url_title}/">{event_start_date format="%l  %j %F, %Y"}: {event_title}</a> 
{/exp:calendar:cal}
```

Comment: Please provide EE and Calendar versions as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing an important parameter in {exp:calendar:cal}: **`pad_short_weeks="n"`**

You'll likely need to have this parameter set to `n` in the event you're trying to display anything other than a typical calendar display. When set to `n`, weeks won't be "padded" to the nearest first day of the week and last day of the week, as Calendar does this by default for the sake of properly outputting and formatting a calendar.

So for example, using the `date_range_start=""` and `date_range_end=""` parameters, if your code looks like this:

```
date_range_start="2011-10-19" date_range_end="2011-10-21"
```

...with `pad_short_weeks=""` parameter NOT specified, Calendar will automatically display the entire week range (2011-10-16 - 2011-10-22). With `pad_short_weeks="n"`, Calendar will just display the selected range (2011-10-19 - 2011-10-21).

[image: pad_short_weeks parameter]